# running a python script as Administrator in Windows

Tags: windows-7, permissions, python, administrator

I have this small Python function:

```
  def change_boot(self):

        subprocess.call(['runas', '/user:Administrator','bcdedit'], shell=True)
```

However it keeps asking for the admin password ... how could i pass it as argument, or bypass it at all?

```
Enter the password for Administrator:
None
```

Comment: Perhaps you could make a batch script which runs your python file and then run the script as an administrator (from the right-click menu)?